# Using Myriad Pro within iPhone app

Tags: iphone, fonts, licensing

I am developing an iOS application for a client and they have a logo that uses the Myriad Pro font family however, as I'm sure you know, this isn't a font built within iOS and I was therefore wondering if I'd be violating any licenses or agreements if I were to download a .ttf file of the font and implement and use the font within the app. The application is a free application by the way and no profits will be made from the app when it's on the App Store.

Comment: If they have a logo that uses the font, they've probably licensed the font (or at least a subset of the font) for use in that logo. But embedding the ENTIRE font's .ttf is definitely going to be outside of that license. Check with the client's graphics artist to see what they've done in the way of licensing BEFORE you go any further. If they've stolen the font outright, then you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely. You don’t have a license to redistribute Myriad Pro, even in a free application. You can use the client’s logo, obviously, since it’s an image *created* with the font and not the font itself, but including the actual TTF in your bundle would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks but they have the logo in the font and therefore they want the application to use the font throughout the application (on tableviews, labels ect.) and this is what I'm getting at, would this be allowed?

Comment: No, it's not allowed, you would be violating the font license agreement. Although Myriad is an OS X system font, and therefore seems 'free', it's not. Legally, it's a piece of software that is sold to you as a part of the operating system, and using the font file in your software is simply illegal.

Comment: …also, that’s a bit of amateurish design that you might want to push back on anyway. Using the same font in the logo and everywhere else dilutes its style. Facebook and Twitter don’t set their apps’ text in their logos’ fonts for a reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments - I think I'm just going to stick with good old Helvetica!